# split stdin into file and terminal

Tags: split, terminal, stdin, csh

I'm looking for a way to split the user keyboard input to a terminal/shell (csh) into a file. For example, if the user types:

```
>make all
>echo bla
```

on the keyboard, then I want this to be shown in the terminal as usual, and also to be written into a file. (i.e. the file will contains "make all""echo bla")

How do I do that in csh/bash?

Comment: Use [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29)?

Comment: @Gassa: I'm not against that, but how would that be done concretely? i.e. would that be something like `csh < tee file`? if yes, I'm not able to get the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `tee logfile | yourprogram`. It saves the output to `logfile` and passes it to `yourprogram` as well.

For example, try to run `tee logstdin | /bin/bash 1>logstdout 2>logstderr` and input the following commands:

```
make all
echo bla
exit
(input something else or just Ctrl+D)
```

Now, `logstdin` contains:

```
make all
echo bla
exit
```

The `logstdout` file is:

```
bla
```

And `logstderr` is the following for me:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: note that I'm looking to split the input (STDIN), not the output.

Comment: @avidane huh, as I see it, it does just that. I expanded the answer with an example.